# How to limit the number of login failures in the MySQL root account

Tags: mysql

I use mysql5.7, my client needs to connect to mysql using navicat, use the root account to log in for 5 consecutive failures to lock the account for 15 minutes. However, googling has turned up no good results.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such feature in Mysql. But you can do this using your application.That's: have a bit column named IsLocked bit and a RetryCount INT column. In your, application, check if it's subsequent login attempt and if it's then increase the RetryCount column.

Once, RetryCount column reaches to 5 (as per your need) update the table set IsLocked column to true.

So, any login attempt after that; just check if the IsLocked column is true and if yes then deny the login and throw validation error message to end user  and unlock account after 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks,Explained to the customer mysql does not have this feature, and can limit the IP connected to mysql. The client accepted the offer.But I am still very interested in this issue, the application refers to the linux shell? Because customers require navicat software login.

Answer (score -2):

There are no such feature in Mysql.  But I think you can let the project manager to delete this feature